# on the fly 2D plots gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to make a plot on the fly with data from a program called "test" using gnuplot.
The output of test looks like:

```
0  1
1  3
2  5
...
```

I would like to do something like `./test | gnuplot`" but I think something is missing
in this command as gnuplot says:  `line 0: invalid command`.

any comment is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your command directly from within gnuplot like with

```
plot '< ./test'
```

Alternatively, something like

```
./test | gnuplot -persist -e "plot '-'"
```

might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a temporary file:

```
./test > temp ; gnuplot -e "plot 'temp'; pause 5" ; rm temp
```